# Onclick event of button placed in each row jqgrid not firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jqgrid

**Situation :** My app carries out an AJAX request and the data received is displayed in the following JQgrid . `listData(data)` is a function that is called in `success` call back of this ajax request ,

`data` is the JSON data received from request .

`buildJqGrid` is a custom function that calls the `.jqgrid()` on a table and div html element .

`buttonFormatter` is my custom formatter for the column named `Action`

```
function listData(data) {
    var containerName = 'datatablea3',
        columnNames = ["Name", 
            "Email", 
            "Language", 
            "Office", 
            "alter email", 
            "Action"
        ],
        columnModels = [{
            name: 'Name',
            index: 'Name',
            width: '200px'
        },{
            name: 'Email',
            index: 'Email',
            width: '200px'
        }, {
            name: 'Language',
            index: 'Language',
            width: '200px'
        }, {
            name: 'Office',
            index: 'Office',
            width: '200px'
        }, {
            name: 'AlterEmail',
            index: 'AlterEmail',
            width: '200px'
        }, {
            name: 'action',
            width: '200px',
            formatter: buttonFormatter
        }],
        sortColumnName = 'Name',
        caption = "Employees",
        rowNum = 25,
        pager = '#pager2a3',
        grouping = false,
        groupingView = {},
        rowList = [25, 50, 100];

    buildJqGrid(containerName, data, columnNames, columnModels,
            sortColumnName, caption, rowNum, pager, grouping, 
                groupingView, rowList, true, 'asc');
}
```

**Problem :** When this jsp is run data is successfully displayed in the `jqgrid` with view button in each record , but when i click on the view button nothing happens !.

I checked in console it shows "control in formatter" but on clicking view button it doesn't show "control in click function".

i also tried using `editLink` formatter but still same error there ,

Can anyone please tell me why my button's `onclick` event is not firing ?

Comment: i think you need do somthing like this 
'<button onclick=\\"click();\\">View</button>';

Comment: could you include **more full JavaScript code** which you use (the code of `buildJqGrid` for example)? Which version of jqGrid and from which fork of jqGrid you use? ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). You current code is very dirty (`width : '200px'` for example should be fixed to numbers: `width: 200`). Binding to Click can be implemented in other way. The best choice depend on the fork and the version of jqGrid, which you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"click" is already a function, and therefore you override it, and nothing fires.

Try this

```
function buttonFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) 
{
console.log("control in button formatter");
 return '<button onclick=\"clickFunction();\">View</button>'; 
} 
function clickFunction()
{
    console.log("control in click function");
    alert("hello");
}
```

Simple fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/5e5LL5po/1/

Comment: Thanks a ton Mam ! It works , could you please explain why my original code didn't work

Comment: @varunsinghal65 no problem :) As I said, you were overriding the original javascript "click" function, which calls the function you want. If you override it, javascript simply doesn't call your own method. I don't know if I'm clear enough, but basically don't override :p

Comment: mam could you please tell me that why my return statement didn't work, and also what do you mean by "click is already a function and therefore you override it and nothing fires  "

Comment: understood , but what is the use of backward slashes while calling clickFunction() why can't i call it without using slash

Comment: @varunsinghal65 https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/5e5LL5po/2/
Button 1 : inline call fires an independant function ; Button 2 : inline call fires self (click) which, there, does nothing (no binding to your function) ; Button 3 : jQuery binding to your function makes it work

Comment: @varunsinghal65 using the slashes just makes sure your quotation marks are rendered. Because you use it as a string, you could have issues. It's not always needed though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107127/discussion-between-varunsinghal65-and-virginielgb).

Answer (score 0):

try like this, I also use same functionality(JQ Grid) in my project, try HTML input type rather than the button,

When using your code, click event was firing but the whole web page is reloading.

```js
function buttonFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    if (rowObject.Status != "Not Started") {
        console.log("Zumbaa");
        var edit = "<input class='Viewbtn'  type='button' value='View' onclick=\"ShowMigrationProcess(" + cellvalue + ");\"  />";
        return edit;
    }
    return '';
}
```